# ethereum mining on Ubuntu 16.04 dropped hashrates significantly on AMD block chain drivers

Tags: 16.04, amd-graphics, ethereum

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to mine ethereum and using claymore dual miner, had the latest Ubuntu block chain drivers installed and the hash rate improved significantly since then until very recently when the hash rate dropped significantly. I have not updated the AMD drivers after the initial installation and I suspect it’s the updates to Ubuntu headers that caused the issue. If any one faced similar issue, please feel free to chip in your ideas

Answer (score 1):

After researching a bit, i found that removing the latest linux-image and linux headers fixed the issue for me. I some how used the package update command recently from console and it updated the linux image and headers

use the following command to find the current installed version of linux image and linux headers

```
dpkg -s linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

Now use the command to remove the linux image. The version that caused the issue for me was 4.13.0-26-generic.

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-4.13.0-26-generic
```

and linux headers

```
sudo apt remove linux-headers-4.13.0-26-generic
reboot
```

The hash rate went back up after this